# WhatsApp restored my older backup, not the latest backup

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

Today, 19th December, I was trying to reset my phone, but I had backed up WhatsApp first.

After that I reboot my phone (Xperia Miro) and installed WhatsApp.
Problem came while WhatsApp was restoring `msgstore-2014-12-13.1.db.crypt7`, not `msgstore-2014-12-19.1.db.crypt7`.

Even though, in folder WhatsApp databases, there are seven backup files: those two files and `msgstore.db.crypt7`, `msgstore-2014-12-12.1.db.crypt7`, `msgstore-2014-12-14.1.db.crypt7`, `msgstore-2014-12-15.1.db.crypt7`, and `msgstore-2014-12-16.1.db.crypt7`.

Why did WhatsApp restore 13th Dec backup? Not 14, 15, neither 16 nor 19?

I have to get 19th December's conversations.

Answer (score 0):

Simply *move* **All backup files** to another folder or *delete* them (If you dont want your old conversations restored in future) **Execpt** backup file you want to restore (i.e - msgstore-2014-12-19.1.db.crypt7 )

-Now again try to restore with whatsapp

-Since there is only one backupfile in `whatsapp` - `databases` folder it will restore that file(i.e backup of 19th December 2014)